# How to hide (or 'display: none') a div when another div's child that is left for display does not contain an image?

Tags: html, jquery, css

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="child1">Some text</div>
    <div class="child2">Some text</div>
    <div class="child3"><img src="#" /></div>
</div>

<div class="div2">...</div> <!-- I want to hide .div2 -->
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {  }

.child1 { display: none }
.child2 { display: block }
.child3 { display: none }

.div2 {  }
```

How to hide `.div2` when what is left to display in `.div1` is a text and not an `img`?

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
if ($(".div1:not(img)").length) { 
$(".div2").hide(); })
```

Comment: `.div1:not(img)` - this would select all elements with the class `div1`, whose element type is not `img` - of which you of course have none here. You would need to build something that uses both [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) (because the elements you hid via `display: none` are only visually hidden, but targeting them using CSS selectors will still find them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```js
$('.div1 > div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible') && $(this).find('img').length > 0) {
    $('.div2').show();
  } else {
    $('.div2').hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.child1 { display: none }
.child2 { display: block }
.child3 { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="child1">Some text</div>
  <div class="child2">Some text</div>
  <div class="child3"><img src="#" /></div>
</div>

<div class="div2">...</div> <!-- I want to hide .div2 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case of trying to achieve with jQuery what CSS can do much simpler.

You can use modern CSS selector [`:has(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) for the job:

```css
.div1:not(:has(img)) ~ .div2 { display: none; }
```